# Angular 2 Observables - Return original observable, instead of switchMap/combineLatest

Tags: angular, firebase

I have a function that makes some calls to a Firebase database that aggregates a bunch of user profile data together. The one issue I'm running into is if the users don't have a `videos` property on their user object, the observable errors out.

Right now, I'm checking to see if there are any videos on the user object. If there are, it returns a new observable that combines a bunch of observables based on the data that it fetches from that `videos` property (an array). However, if there aren't, I need to return the original observable before the `.switchMap()`.

Does anyone know what I need to tweak here?

Here's my function:

```
getUserProfile(id) {
    return this._af.database
      .object(`/social/users/${id}`)

      // Switch to the joined observable

      .switchMap((user) => {

        let vidKeys = Object.keys(user.videos);

        if(vidKeys && vidKeys.length > 0) {
          // Use forkJoin to join the video observables. The observables will
          // need to complete, so first is used. And use forkJoin's selector to
          // map the videos to the user and then return the user.

          return Observable.combineLatest(
            vidKeys.map((vidKey) => this._af.database
              .object(`/social/videos/${vidKey}`)
            ),
            (...videos) => {
              vidKeys.forEach((vidKey, index) => {

                // Query YouTube api to get the duration
                this._yt.getVideo(vidKey).subscribe(data => {

                  // Format the duration
                  let duration = this._yt.convertToStandardDuration(data.items[0].contentDetails.duration)
                  videos[index]['duration'] = duration;
                  user.videos[vidKey] = videos[index];

                });

               });
              return user;
            }
          )
        } else {

          // TO-DO: Return original observable that was called before the .switchMap()

        }
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to return the original observable, you only have to return an observable that emits the original value, as the `switchMap` will be invoked when original observable re-emits. You can do that with `Observable.of`:

```js
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

getUserProfile(id) {
  return this._af.database
    .object(`/social/users/${id}`)
    .switchMap((user) => {

      let vidKeys = Object.keys(user.videos);

      if(vidKeys && vidKeys.length > 0) {
        ...
      } else {
        return Observable.of(user);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: you save me yet again. Would you believe I was actually trying something like `return Observable.of([])`, just to see if the call would complete? :) Thanks again. Cheers!